# Deriving conditional PDF from piecewise marginals

Tags: probability

I have the following joint PDF $$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\frac{1}{10},(x,y)\in[-1,1]\times[-2,2]\cup[1,2]\times[-1,1]$$ and I am trying to find $f_{X|Y}(x|y)$ and $f_{Y|X}(y|x)$.

So far I have found that the marginal PDFs of *X* and *Y* are $$f_X(x)=\frac{2}{5},x\in[-1,1]; f_x(x)=\frac{1}{5},x\in[1,2]$$ and $$f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{5},y\in[-2,-1]\cup[1,2];f_Y(y)=\frac{3}{10},y\in[-1,1]$$ respectively.

However, I am having trouble finding the conditional distributions as each of the marginals is divided into cases. Any hints/suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $$f_{X|Y}(x|y) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_{Y}(y)}$$ and that $$f_{Y|X}(y|x) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_{X}(x)}$$

These equalities hold true pointwise for every $(x,y)$ in $[-1,1] \times [-2,2] \cup [1,2] \times [-1,1]$. Therefore, to find $f_{X|Y}(x|y)$, divide $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ by $\frac{2}{5}$ for $x \in [-1,1]$ and by $\frac{1}{5}$ for $x \in [1,2]$, and to find $f_{Y|X}(y|x)$, divide $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ by $\frac{1}{5}$ for $y \in [-2,-1] \cup [1, 2]$ and by $\frac{3}{10}$ for $y \in [-1,1]$. This gives:

$$
\begin{align*}
f_{Y|X}(y|x) &= \frac{1}{4}, (x,y) \in [-1,1] \times [-2,2]; \frac{1}{2}, (x,y) \in [1,2] \times [-1,1]\\
f_{X|Y}(x|y) &= \frac{1}{2}, (x,y) \in [-1,1] \times [-2,-1] \cup [-1,1] \times [1,2];\frac{1}{3}, (x,y) \in [-1,2] \times [-1,1]
\end{align*}
$$

Note that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{Y|X}(y|x) \,dy = 1 \, \forall \, x \in [-1,2]$ and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X|Y}(x|y) \,dx = 1 \, \forall \, y \in [-2,2]$ as it should.

Comment: Thanks! So if I then wanted to find $\mathbb{E}[X|Y]$, for example, I would compute $\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{x}{2}dx+\int_{-1}^2\frac{x}{3}dx$ ?

Comment: Not quite. $\mathbb{E}[X|Y]$ in this case is a function of $y$ equal to $\int_{-1}^1 \frac{x}{2} \,dx$ when $y \in [-2,-1] \cup [1, 2]$ and $\int_{-1}^2 \frac{x}{3} \,dx$ when $y \in [-1, 1]$.